# Border not drawing of included TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

this is my first time using TikZ and drew a standalone diagramm like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

% math packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

% tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    positioning,
    shadows,
    arrows,
    arrows.meta,
    fit,
    intersections,
    calc
}

% eigene styles definieren
\tikzset{%
    block/.style = {draw, thick, rectangle, drop shadow, fill = white},
    sum/.style = {draw, thick, circle, drop shadow, inner sep = .8mm, fill=white},
    point/.style = {coordinate}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, >=Triangle]
    
    \draw
    node [block,minimum height=8em] (sys) {Klärschlammverbrennungsanalge};

    \draw[->] (sys.10)--node[]{$T_B(t)$}(5,0.5);
    \draw[->] (sys.-10)--node[]{$C_{O_2}(t)$}(5,-0.5);
    \draw[->] (-5,0.5)--node[]{$\dot{m}_P(t)$}(-2.65,0.5);
    \draw[->] (-5,-0.5)--node[]{$\dot{m}_L(t)$}(-2.65,-0.5);
    
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

And I wanted to include that TikZ into my main `.tex`, but the border around the node is not being drawn. Only the arrows and the text is displayed correctly. Any clue why this happens?

This is how I include it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{BasicSystem}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Edit: This is what it looks like alone and when its included
[image][image]

Comment: You're missing semicolons at the end of the last four `\draw`s. (Also, I don't think you should write `Klärschlammverbrennungsanalge` in math mode, I suggest removing the dollar signs around that.)

Comment: I added your suggestions but the Node still doesnt have any border in my main file.. @TorbjørnT. I just updated the questions with an example if the problem I am facing.

Comment: What is the class of the document you are using?

Comment: Its an `article`

Comment: Can you turn both files into complete documents? It worked fine when I tested.

Comment: Your diagram is not produced with the standalone class?

Comment: @AndréC It is. I updated the questions to the full source code of the diagramm.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I updated the question with the whole code I was using. It doesnt work..

Comment: And as a native German I have to add, you probably mean a „Klärschlammverbrennungsanlage”, so there is a typo. ;-)

Comment: I see you got an answer below, but another thing: The arrows to/from the `sys` node can be created more conveniently with relative coordinates: `\draw[->] (sys.10) -- node {$T_B(t)$} +(2,0);   \draw[->] (sys.-10) -- node {$C_{O_2}(t)$} +(2,0);  \draw[<-] (sys.170) -- node {$\dot{m}_P(t)$} +(-2,0);  \draw[<-] (sys.190) -- node {$\dot{m}_L(t)$} +(-2,0);`  See chapter 13.4 *Relative and Incremental Coordinates* in the TikZ manual.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Hi, based on you suggestions for `tikz` arrows, I've added a modified example to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In short:**

Change `\usepackage{standalone}` to `\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}`.

**More detailed explanation:**

From the [documentation of `standalone](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf), section 6.2,

> The `standalone` package removes all sub-file preambles (“sub-preambles”) by
> default when loaded. However, if the package is loaded with the `subpreambles`
> options, all sub-preambles are stored ...

Change `\usepackage{standalone}` to `\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}`, then the preamble of sub-file that loads `tikz` libraries and defines `tikz` options is used, and the frame/border around node `(sys)` is drawn.

---

**On making arrows in that `tikzpicture` more consistent**

(based on the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553400/border-not-drawing-of-included-tikz/553412#comment1397156_553400) by  @TorbjørnT)

The aim is to make those four arrows having equal length (2cm), level horizontal direction, and pair to pair equal height.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

% math packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

% tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    positioning,
    shadows,
    arrows,
    arrows.meta,
    fit,
    intersections,
    calc
}

% eigene styles definieren
\tikzset{%
    block/.style = {draw, thick, rectangle, drop shadow, fill = white},
    sum/.style = {draw, thick, circle, drop shadow, inner sep = .8mm, fill=white},
    point/.style = {coordinate}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, >=Triangle]

    \node[block,minimum height=8em] (sys) {Klärschlammverbrennungsanalge};

    \draw[->] (sys.10)   -- node        {$T_B(t)$}       +(2, 0);
    \draw[->] (sys.-10)  -- node        {$C_{O_2}(t)$}   +(2, 0);
    \draw[<-] (sys.170)  -- node[above] {$\dot{m}_P(t)$} +(-2, 0);
    \draw[<-] (sys.-170) -- node[above] {$\dot{m}_L(t)$} +(-2, 0);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Edit! I will use that!

Comment: I was just working again and now the `[subpreambles]` causes an Error I dont really understand..

Comment: @HWilmer You can post a follow-up question to ask about that error, with [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and message of the first reported error.