# Using [subpreambles]{standalone} causes the document to not compile

Tags: tex-core, standalone

Yesterday I had [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553400/border-not-drawing-of-included-tikz?noredirect=1#comment1397165_553400) problem which was quickly resolved, but now the Solution doesn't work anymore.

The problem happens with this small piece of code already:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
Foo!

\end{document}
```

The error message says the follwing:

```
The File ended while scanning text of \write.
Extra \Fi.
Runaway Argument?
Undefined control sequence.
Missing number, treated as zero.
Missing { inserted.
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Note that without `[subpreambles]` it does work and it also worked yesterday but somehow not today.

Comment: show the log-file of your small example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just wanted to copy them and since I am using Overleaf I thought maybe I should just clear the Cache and that did actually the trick and it works now again. Weird..